# Code injection in Python modules

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an "image" class which exposes a method named "**`.extent()`**" and this class is a subclass of `numpy.ndarray`.

So, I can call

```
im = image( ( 256, 256 ), extent = ( 0.0, 3.14, -1.0, 1.0 ) )
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow( im, extent = im.extent() )
```

What I really would like to do is to inject code so that "**`.imshow()`**" in order to be able to call simply

```
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow( im )
```

and to have "**`.imshow()`**" to set the extent automatically.

Writing another function to do so is trivial, but I want to have "`matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()`" to do it.

**So, my question is:**

Is it possible to a model, written by me, to inject code inside a function from other module?

**If so, how?**

Comment: Since `imshow` is not defined as a protocol (such as the `iterator` protocol which works by the `next` function or the descriptor protocol which works through `property`) then you cannot expect `imshow` to disassemble objects that are passed to it and to behave different for different types of objects, beyond whatever extent this happens already in the source code of `imshow`. If "showing" was implemented as an interface, as in say Haskell, then you could just ensure your class implements the interface. But this is not how `matplotlib` has chosen to work.

Comment: While you can simply rename things to put a new function in for `imshow` (as in Joran Beasley's answer) this usually causes more harm than good, especially for people picking up your code and expecting a `matplotlib` standard function like `imshow` to work with a certain calling signature and finding that instead it's been monkeypatched with your custom function. In most cases, it's better to just write a new function or have a class method that handles inducing the correct `imshow` call.

Comment: @EMS, I don't agree with this latter comment. It is perfectly possible to do something different from the expected only when the argument is of my "image" class.

Comment: But not by using the existing source code of `imshow`. It was not implemented that way. It has no hooks for any code injection to make it behave differently (which is what it would have if it was an interface). Of course you can make a new function that first checks whether the argument is of your type, dispatches the right call, or else just calls `imshow` the regular way. --- making a new function --- Which is something you said you did not want.

Answer (score 4):

```
original = matplotlib.pyplot.imshow
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow = lambda x: original(x, extent=x.extent())
```

is one way to do it I suppose

or even better as suggested in the comments

```
imshow = lambda x:matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(x,extent=x.extent())
```

even though it doesnt "inject code"

Comment: Even better would be if the OP could forego the requirement that it has to be `matplotlib`'s `imshow` that invokes like this, and simply give that `lambda` a new name.